# Distinguish Numpad from non-Numpad key presses when Numlock-off

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I'm working on a little tray application that runs an action when a numpad key is pressed **while the Numlock is off** - with the following conditions:

1. The application listens to the key presses even when it's out of focus.
2. The app ***MUST*** distinguish between numpad vs. non-numpad keys that have the same effect (e.g. Numpad7 acts like Home when Numlock is off vs. Dedicated Home button on the keyboard).

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27309185/10273535) to register my global hotkeys so that the app listens to the keypresses while out-of-focus. The app runs but both Numpad7 and Home return the same keycode.

I also looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5989521/10273535) which gave me some insight that `m.LParam.ToInt32() >> 24 == 1` implies Numpad key press, which didn't work for all keys (only seems to work for Enter/Return).

I have found [this excellent Javascript-run website](https://keycode.info/) that actually checks the ***location*** of the keypress, returning Numpad when any numpad key is pressed with Numlock both on or off.

**Any idea how to get a similar Numpad Keypress check in C#?**

[image]

---

**UPDATE:**

Experimenting with what @Jimi suggested on the comments below, I have noticed that when checking against `m.MSG == WM_KEYDOWN`, evaluating `m.LParam >> 24` results in `0` for non-Numpad keys, and `1` for Numpad keys. However, my application is checking against `WM_HOTKEY`, in order to listen to keypresses when the application is **out of focus**.

Here's how my `WNdProc` method looks like:

```c#
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(ref m);

    // check if we got a hot key pressed.
    if (m.Msg == 0x0312) // check if WM_HOTKEY
    {
        // get the keys.
        Keys key = (Keys)(((int)m.LParam >> 16) & 0xFFFF);
        ModifierKeys modifier = (ModifierKeys)((int)m.LParam & 0xFFFF);
        
        // here m.LParam is identical for both numpad-home and non-numpad home
        bool isNumpad = ((int)m.LParam >> 24) == 0;

        // invoke the event to notify the parent.
        if (KeyPressed != null)
            KeyPressed(this, new KeyPressedEventArgs(modifier, key, isNumpad));
    }
}
```

There isn't any obvious way in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-hotkey) of `WM_HOTKEY` to check if the hotkey pressed is part of extended keyboard.

Comment: Have you read this? It may be helpful to check for this state in your handler. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6135211/8695782

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find the state of NumLock, CapsLock and ScrollLock in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577411/how-can-i-find-the-state-of-numlock-capslock-and-scrolllock-in-net)

Comment: My code already implements your suggestions as a way to ensure Numlock is indeed off before triggering the action. However, what I'm looking for is a way to distinguish (for example) NumpadHome (which is Numpad 7 when Numlock is off) from OEM Home keys, as they both return the same value (Keys.Home).

Comment: If you trap `WM_KEYDOWN`, `wParam` shows the same key (e.g., `Keys.Home = 0x24`, but the value of `lParam` is not the same when the Numeric Pad is used)

Comment: In case the Docs are not clear enough, test whether bit 24 is set. If it's not, it's your NumPad.

Comment: @Jimi - you're absolutely right! I did some experimentation and indeed bit 24 is set to 1 on the Numpad as the documentation mentions. Turned out my issue was I'm checking for bit 24 while trapping `WM_HOTKEY`, which is what I need for my app to listen for hotkeys while the form is out of focus. When trapping `WM_HOTKEY`, `lParam` is identical for `Home` and `NumpadHome`. Any idea how to go about performing the same check when capturing `WM_HOTKEY` instead?

Comment: @Jimi I've updated the question with sample code to clarify what I'm after.